# expss how to have two different total rows for one statistic

Tags: r, expss

I would like to have an expss banner table with column percents, a total row at the very top with weighted valid n, and a total row below each stub with weighted valid percent. I have tried adding two statistics like below, however I end up duplicating the rows. Is there a way I can remove the duplicated rows? Or add two totals rows for one statistic?

I am writing to excel using `expss::xl_write` and I tried using `remove_repeated = "rows"` with no success. It only removed the first repeated row. I also am going to be creating a lot of these with the same banners using functions.

This is when I tried adding the statistic twice:

```
mtcars = apply_labels(mtcars,
                      cyl = "Number of cylinders",
                      am = "Transmission",
                      am = c("Automatic" = 0,
                             "Manual"=1),
                      period = "Measurement period",
                      vs = "Engine",
                      vs = c("V-Shaped" = 0,
                             "Straight"=1)
)

mtcars %>% 
      tab_cells(cyl, vs) %>% 
      tab_cols(total(), am) %>% 
      tab_stat_cpct(total_row_position = c("above"),
                    total_statistic = c("w_responses"),
                    total_label = "Total N") %>% 
      tab_stat_cpct(total_row_position = c("below"),
                    total_statistic = c("w_cpct"),
                    total_label = "Total %") %>%       
      tab_pivot()
```

```
 |                     |          | #Total | Transmission |        |
 |                     |          |        |    Automatic | Manual |
 | ------------------- | -------- | ------ | ------------ | ------ |
 | Number of cylinders | #Total N |   32.0 |         19.0 |   13.0 |
 |                     |        4 |   34.4 |         15.8 |   61.5 |
 |                     |        6 |   21.9 |         21.1 |   23.1 |
 |                     |        8 |   43.8 |         63.2 |   15.4 |
 |              Engine | #Total N |   32.0 |         19.0 |   13.0 |
 |                     | V-Shaped |   56.2 |         63.2 |   46.2 |
 |                     | Straight |   43.8 |         36.8 |   53.8 |
 | Number of cylinders |        4 |   34.4 |         15.8 |   61.5 |
 |                     |        6 |   21.9 |         21.1 |   23.1 |
 |                     |        8 |   43.8 |         63.2 |   15.4 |
 |                     | #Total % |  100.0 |        100.0 |  100.0 |
 |              Engine | V-Shaped |   56.2 |         63.2 |   46.2 |
 |                     | Straight |   43.8 |         36.8 |   53.8 |
 |                     | #Total % |  100.0 |        100.0 |  100.0 |
```

I tried splitting the table in two, like [on this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74066207/expss-how-to-add-total-statistics-only-once-even-if-several-variables-are-specif)

```
mtcars %>% 
      tab_cols(total(), am) %>% 
      tab_cells(cyl) %>% 
      tab_stat_cpct(total_row_position = c("above"),
                    total_statistic = c("w_responses"),
                    total_label = "Total N") %>% 
      tab_cells(vs) %>% 
      tab_stat_cpct(total_row_position = c("below"),
                    total_statistic = c("w_cpct"),
                    total_label = "Total %") %>%       
      tab_pivot()
```

And I get this, which is close but I don't get the column percent on both.

```
                                                                    
 |                     |          | #Total | Transmission |        |
 |                     |          |        |    Automatic | Manual |
 | ------------------- | -------- | ------ | ------------ | ------ |
 | Number of cylinders | #Total N |   32.0 |         19.0 |   13.0 |
 |                     |        4 |   34.4 |         15.8 |   61.5 |
 |                     |        6 |   21.9 |         21.1 |   23.1 |
 |                     |        8 |   43.8 |         63.2 |   15.4 |
 |              Engine | V-Shaped |   56.2 |         63.2 |   46.2 |
 |                     | Straight |   43.8 |         36.8 |   53.8 |
 |                     | #Total % |  100.0 |        100.0 |  100.0 |
```

This is what I want:

```
 |                     |          | #Total | Transmission |        |
 |                     |          |        |    Automatic | Manual |
 | ------------------- | -------- | ------ | ------------ | ------ |
 | Number of cylinders | #Total N |   32.0 |         19.0 |   13.0 |
 |                     |        4 |   34.4 |         15.8 |   61.5 |
 |                     |        6 |   21.9 |         21.1 |   23.1 |
 |                     |        8 |   43.8 |         63.2 |   15.4 |
 |                     | #Total % |  100.0 |        100.0 |  100.0 |
 |             Engine  | V-Shaped |   56.2 |         63.2 |   46.2 |
 |                     | Straight |   43.8 |         36.8 |   53.8 |
 |                     | #Total % |  100.0 |        100.0 |  100.0 |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems, the simplest method is to use `subtotal`:

```
mtcars %>% 
    tab_cols(total(), am) %>% 
    # other() means all other categories. If use it alone it will use all categories.
    tab_cells(subtotal(cyl, "#Total %" = other()), subtotal(vs, "#Total %" = other())) %>% 
    tab_stat_cpct(total_row_position = c("above"),
                  total_statistic = c("w_responses"),
                  total_label = c("Total N")) %>% 
    tab_pivot()
```

UPDATE:
Sorry, I misunderstood you question. The appropriate answer is:

```
mtcars %>% 
    tab_cols(total(), am) %>%
    # block especially for top total 
    tab_cells(total(cyl, label = "#Total N")) %>% 
    tab_stat_cases(total_row_position = "none") %>% 
    # end of block
    tab_cells(cyl, vs) %>% 
    tab_stat_cpct(total_row_position = c("below"),
                  total_statistic = c("w_cpct"),
                  total_label = c("Total %")) %>% 
    tab_pivot()
```